# Intellij-idea's Intellisense cannot recognize Spring's static resource mapping in html

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I want Intellisense to work properly with spring-managed links to **static resources** in my jsp/html views, like this:

```
<img src="/public/image.jpg"/>
```

Even though working application runs without errors, Intellisense warns me:

```
Cannot resolve controller URL '/public/image.jpg'
```

Adding resource mapping **programmatically**:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/public/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");

}
```

I even tried defining mapping in **spring-mvc's config file**:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/public/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources"/>
```

and importing it in web context by **@ImportResource** annotation:

```
@ImportResource("/META-INF/spring-resources.xml")
```

Overall Spring facet works fine but this.

Edit:
I tried all combinations configuring spring facet - no effect.

**pom.xml** :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.name</groupId>
<artifactId>name</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--Springframework-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!--Springframework-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--Servlet Api-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.M13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSTL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--DATABASE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.40</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--TEST-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: check your project's source folders - make sure the `/public/` folder is listed there - `File > Project Structure` then at the dialog select `Modules` from the left panel; the project (top-level) in the middle panel; On the right panel 'Sources' tab

Comment: @ochi i'm very sorry, but i don't want to include folders manually, i want spring facet to resolve it automatically by declaring resource mapping

Comment: I see.  Is this a maven project? I don't seem to have this issue with my projects (but they are all maven-based)

Comment: @ochi Yes, it is a maven project. I can add **pom.xml** to post, if it can help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems to be a bug.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000138310-Cannot-resolve-controller-URL-on-a-Spring-Boot-Example-Project